# How to format a number into a fixed string size, in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, string, string-formatting

I'm displaying GUID's and Numbers in a simple text output report. How can i keep the length of each string 'fixed'.

eg. Currently, this is what is happening. (BAD).

```
[WaWorkerHost.exe] +-----------------------------------------------------------+
[WaWorkerHost.exe] +  RavenDb Initialization Report                            +
[WaWorkerHost.exe] +  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                            +
[WaWorkerHost.exe] +  o) Tenant Id: 50f1bf7f-7936-4aa9-aeca-e47b1d61bb85       +
[WaWorkerHost.exe] +  o) Number of Documents: 87                            +
[WaWorkerHost.exe] +  o) Number of Indexes: 5                            +
[WaWorkerHost.exe] +  o) Number of ~Stale Indexes: 0                            +
[WaWorkerHost.exe] +-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

and what i'm after...

```
[WaWorkerHost.exe] +-----------------------------------------------------------+
[WaWorkerHost.exe] +  RavenDb Initialization Report                            +
[WaWorkerHost.exe] +  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                            +
[WaWorkerHost.exe] +  o) Tenant Id: 50f1bf7f-7936-4aa9-aeca-e47b1d61bb85       +
[WaWorkerHost.exe] +  o) Number of Documents: 87                               +
[WaWorkerHost.exe] +  o) Number of Indexes: 5                                  +
[WaWorkerHost.exe] +  o) Number of ~Stale Indexes: 0                           +
[WaWorkerHost.exe] +-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

cheers!

(note: the guid is a fixed length, so that line has 'hardcoded' spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With string formatting:

```
static string BoxLine(int totalWidth, string format, params object[] args)
{
    string s = String.Format(format, args);
    return "+ " + s.PadRight(totalWidth - 4) + " +";
}

static string BoxStartEnd(int totalWidth)
{
    return "+" + new String('-',totalWidth-2) + "+";
}
```

Call it just like `String.Format` but with the width in there:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const int BoxWidth = 40;

    Console.WriteLine( BoxStartEnd(BoxWidth) );
    Console.WriteLine( BoxLine(BoxWidth, "Does this work: {0} {1}", 42, 64) );
    Console.WriteLine( BoxLine(BoxWidth, " -->Yep<--") );
    Console.WriteLine( BoxStartEnd(BoxWidth) );

    Console.Read();    
}
```

Output:

```
+--------------------------------------+
+ Does this work: 42 64                +
+  -->Yep<--                           +
+--------------------------------------+
```

- [`String.PadRight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34d75d7s.aspx)

Comment: OMG. this is an embarrassing and awkward moment.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to give exact solution, because you presented no source code context. Consider next code as an example of building your report:

```
var header = string.Format("Tenant Id: {0,-43}+", Guid.NewGuid());

var docCount = 87;
var indexesCount = 5;
var staleIndexesCount = 0;


string secondRow = string.Format("Number of Documents: {0,-33}+", docCount);
string thirdRow = string.Format("Number of Indexes: {0,-35}+", indexesCount);
string fourthRow = string.Format("Number of of ~Stale Indexes: {0,-25}+", staleIndexesCount);

Console.WriteLine (header);
Console.WriteLine (secondRow);
Console.WriteLine (thirdRow);
Console.WriteLine (fourthRow);
```

will print:

```
Tenant Id: 90814671-a5e6-48c6-ad4a-a816e7611c65       +
Number of Documents: 87                               +
Number of Indexes: 5                                  +
Number of of ~Stale Indexes: 0                        +
```

Comment: ...and manually figure out the alignment for every different line?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart OP clearly noted about hardcoded width. I've commented that my solution serves only as an example. Your's obviously more generic and clean, that's basically why I upvoted it...

Answer (score 0):

You have to know width you are aiming for.

After you calculate that, use `PadRight` to get a string of a required length. You can also use `string.Format` padding support, but it may result in a less maintainable code if your width is not fixed.